ElasticSearch And Kibana With SSL Connect Refused(Kibana always connect to 127.0.0.1:9200)
I built my ES and Kibana through docker-compose File like this
And my question is: my Kibana service cant connect to my Es, whether I change my docker-compose file or kibana.yml , kibana always connect to 127.0.0.1:9200 and error with connect refused
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
    restart: always
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=$ELASTIC_PASSWORD
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=trial 
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate 
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.key
    volumes: ['data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data', 'certs:$CERTS_DIR']
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --cacert $CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt -s https://localhost:9200 >/dev/null; if [[ $$? == 52 ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  es02:
    container_name: es02
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=$ELASTIC_PASSWORD
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=trial
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate 
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.key
    volumes: ['data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data', 'certs:$CERTS_DIR']
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
  es03:
    container_name: es03
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=$ELASTIC_PASSWORD
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=trial
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate 
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.key
    volumes: ['data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data', 'certs:$CERTS_DIR']
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
  
  wait_until_ready:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
    command: /usr/bin/true
    depends_on: {"es01": {"condition": "service_healthy"}}
  
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.14.0
    restart: always
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      - SERVER_NAME= kibana
      - SERVER_HOSE= 0.0.0.0
      - elasticsearch.hosts= https://myIp:92000
      - SERVER_SSL_ENABLED=true
      - SERVER_SSL_CERTIFICATE=$KIBANA_CERTS_DIR/kibana.crt
      - SERVER_SSL_KEY=$KIBANA_CERTS_DIR/kibana.key
        #- ELASTICSEARCH.USERNAME=kibana_system
        #- ELASTICSEARCH.PASSWORD=$KIBANA_PASSWORD
      - ELASTICSEARCH.SSL.CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=$KIBANA_CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - ELASTICSEARCH.SSL.VERIFICATIONMODE=certificate
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.encryptionKey="SOMETHING_CODE_ENCRYPTIONKEY_HERE"
      - xpack.reporting.encryptionKey="SOMETHING_CODE_ENCRYPTIONKEY_HERE"
      - i18n.locale=zh-CN
      - TZ=Asia/Shanghai
    volumes: ['./kibana:$KIBANA_CERTS_DIR','/home/bali16/service/kibana/config/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml']
    depends_on:
      - es01
      - es02
      - es03
volumes: {"data01", "data02","data03","certs"}

and here is my kibana container logs
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:00+08:00","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":1213,"message":"Plugin \"metricsEntities\" is disabled."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:00+08:00","tags":["warning","config","deprecation"],"pid":1213,"message":"plugins.scanDirs is deprecated and is no longer used"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:00+08:00","tags":["warning","config","deprecation"],"pid":1213,"message":"Config key [monitoring.cluster_alerts.email_notifications.email_address] will be required for email notifications to work in 8.0.\""}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:00+08:00","tags":["warning","config","deprecation"],"pid":1213,"message":"\"xpack.reporting.roles\" is deprecated. Granting reporting privilege through a \"reporting_user\" role will not be supported starting in 8.0. Please set \"xpack.reporting.roles.enabled\" to \"false\" and grant reporting privileges to users using Kibana application privileges **Management > Security > Roles**."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:00+08:00","tags":["info","http","server","NotReady"],"pid":1213,"message":"http server running at https://localhost:5601"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:01+08:00","tags":["info","plugins-system"],"pid":1213,"message":"Setting up [106] plugins: [translations,taskManager,licensing,globalSearch,globalSearchProviders,banners,licenseApiGuard,code,usageCollection,xpackLegacy,telemetryCollectionManager,telemetryCollectionXpack,kibanaUsageCollection,securityOss,share,screenshotMode,telemetry,newsfeed,mapsEms,mapsLegacy,legacyExport,kibanaLegacy,embeddable,uiActionsEnhanced,expressions,charts,esUiShared,bfetch,data,savedObjects,visualizations,visTypeXy,visTypeVislib,visTypeTimelion,features,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeTable,visTypePie,visTypeMetric,visTypeMarkdown,tileMap,regionMap,presentationUtil,timelion,home,searchprofiler,painlessLab,grokdebugger,graph,visTypeVega,management,watcher,licenseManagement,indexPatternManagement,advancedSettings,discover,discoverEnhanced,dashboard,dashboardEnhanced,visualize,visTypeTimeseries,savedObjectsManagement,spaces,security,transform,savedObjectsTagging,lens,reporting,canvas,lists,ingestPipelines,fileUpload,maps,dataVisualizer,encryptedSavedObjects,dataEnhanced,timelines,dashboardMode,cloud,upgradeAssistant,snapshotRestore,fleet,indexManagement,rollup,remoteClusters,crossClusterReplication,indexLifecycleManagement,enterpriseSearch,eventLog,actions,alerting,triggersActionsUi,stackAlerts,ruleRegistry,osquery,ml,cases,securitySolution,observability,uptime,infra,monitoring,logstash,console,apmOss,apm]"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:01+08:00","tags":["info","plugins","taskManager"],"pid":1213,"message":"TaskManager is identified by the Kibana UUID: c8256dfe-2b3f-4c1f-86bc-896ae35eba61"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:04+08:00","tags":["warning","plugins","security","config"],"pid":1213,"message":"Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:04+08:00","tags":["warning","plugins","reporting","config"],"pid":1213,"message":"Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:04+08:00","tags":["warning","plugins","reporting","config"],"pid":1213,"message":"Chromium sandbox provides an additional layer of protection, but is not supported for Linux CentOS 8.4.2105\n OS. Automatically setting 'xpack.reporting.capture.browser.chromium.disableSandbox: true'."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:04+08:00","tags":["warning","plugins","encryptedSavedObjects"],"pid":1213,"message":"Saved objects encryption key is not set. This will severely limit Kibana functionality. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:04+08:00","tags":["warning","plugins","actions","actions"],"pid":1213,"message":"APIs are disabled because the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin is missing encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:04+08:00","tags":["warning","plugins","alerting","plugins","alerting"],"pid":1213,"message":"APIs are disabled because the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin is missing encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:10+08:00","tags":["info","plugins","ruleRegistry"],"pid":1213,"message":"Write is disabled, not installing assets"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:10+08:00","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":1213,"message":"Waiting until all Elasticsearch nodes are compatible with Kibana before starting saved objects migrations..."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-04-17T16:26:10+08:00","tags":["error","savedobjects-service"],"pid":1213,"message":"Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}

As you look in kibana log,
Even the port of elasticsearch.hosts is 92000 in my docker-compose file, it always connect to 127.0.0.1 (by the way , the port in my kibana.yml is 92001, it also useless :( )
And then , I can visit and operate my Es with username and password on browser, it is prove that my es is OK
So do I have any problems with my configuration?
How should I solve the problem of the Kibana connect? It seems like when I don’t configure the SSL of the ES and Kibana, they can connected successfully
--------------edit-----------------
Supplement the content of the creation certificate


Are the ca.crt-files identical for Kibana and Elastic?

Hi @Teemu Risikko, the ca.crt file for Kibana and Elastic is the same file, and it is created identically by create-certs.yml, where instance.yml lists Kibana and Elastic.

ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS instead of elasticsearch.hosts should work. See What is the syntax for ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS in docker-compose? for more information, but:
kibana:
  ...
  environment:
    ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://es01:9200","http://es02:9200","http://es03:9200"]'


Thanks for all. It looks like my Kibana can connect to Elasticsearch, but another problem has occurred. Could you plz check for me? The Kibana logs show an error message:  Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. unable to verify the first certificate
